# Which of the design patterns (with or without SQS) below should they use to process spiked data volume in AWS?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I am doing my AWS study and came across this seemly debatable question online, wondering if posting here can get more inputs:

A company is building a voting system for a popular TV show, viewers win watch the performances then visit
the show’s website to vote for their favorite performer. It is expected that in a short period of time after the
show has finished **the site will receive millions of visitors**. The visitors will first login to the site using their
Amazon.com credentials and then submit their vote. After the voting is completed the page will display the
vote totals. The company needs to build the site such that can handle the rapid influx of traffic while
maintaining good performance but also wants to keep costs to a minimum. Which of the design patterns
below should they use?

> A. Use CloudFront and an Elastic Load balancer in front of an
>   auto-scaled set of web servers, the web servers will first can the
>   Login With Amazon service to authenticate the user then process the
>   users vote and store the result into a multi-AZ Relational Database
>   Service instance.
>
> B. Use CloudFront and the static website hosting feature of S3 with
>   the Javascript SDK to call the Login With Amazon service to
>   authenticate the user, use IAM Roles to gain permissions to a DynamoDB
>   table to store the users vote.
>
> C. Use CloudFront and an Elastic Load Balancer in front of an
>   auto-scaled set of web servers, the web servers will first call the
>   Login with Amazon service to authenticate the user, the web servers
>   will process the users vote and store the result into a DynamoDB table
>   using IAM Roles for EC2 instances to gain permissions to the DynamoDB
>   table.
>
> D. Use CloudFront and an Elastic Load Balancer in front of an
>   auto-scaled set of web servers, the web servers will first call the
>   Login. With Amazon service to authenticate the user, the web servers
>   win process the users vote and store the result into an SQS queue
>   using IAM Roles for EC2 Instances to gain permissions to the SQS
>   queue. A set of application servers will then retrieve the items from
>   the queue and store the result into a DynamoDB table.

The original question is from 
http://www.briefmenow.org/amazon/which-of-the-design-patterns-below-should-they-use/#comment-25822
and it is very debatable there.

My thought is limit the numbers of AWS service so that the cost is minimum. RDS is excluded here for there are three options pointing to DynamoDB (I am not a cloud guru, this is my instinct judgement). S3 is only good for static website, so B is excluded.

Between C & D I chose C as 1. it doesn't need to use SQS which is an extra cost; 2. does SQS come with the capability to process the volume in an expected IOPS/Throughput? I don't know but both C & D use DynamoDB which is what I think a good solution and D doesn't indicate the needed permission for the application servers (i.e. EC2 instances) to obtain access to DynamoDB. So D is excluded here.

Am I missing anything here?

There is no standard and authority answer provided for this question.

Thank you very much for the discussion.

Comment: more component != more cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly opinionated question.

This is one way to solve the problem.

**Design considerations**

1. High number of requests in a short span of time

   a. we must be able to autoscale

   b. write traffic should be spread out so that we don't have to provision lots of dynamodb capacity.

   c. read should not require doing database join and count operation, so that we don't have to provision lots of RAM, dynamodb capacity.

**Assumptions**

1. Eventual consistency of votes is fine.
2. Write should be strongly consistent. (if votes are immutable(can not be changed once done) it may fine to use sqs otherwise bringing in sqs brings in lot of complexities in the system. as explained below)

**Architecture**
[image]

**Components**

1. Use CloudFront and the static website hosting feature of S3 for powering website. (so that horizontally scalable.) (**PS** this approach is called client side rendering and has multiple cons like seo, do your research before choosing this approach, if you need server side rendering have another server behind aws elb which calls other services and creates the page. [these](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143194/what-advantages-are-conferred-by-using-server-side-page-rendering) are pros and cons of both the approaches, for the rest of answer i assume you are doing server side rendering.)
2. Website calls your services to render the page.
3. Your service is deployed on ec2, with auto scaling enabled.
4. All the reads are served from elastic-cache (they are deployed in master slave configuration so that no single point of failure).
5. All the writes go to dynamodb consistently. (Most of the services need to get consistent state to decide next state, if we have sqs queue in between if becomes impossible to determine exact state of system any given point of time. But this also means that we need to pay more for dynamodb. For this enable auto-scaling on dynamodb.)
6. Since major share of the load would be read, keep the aggregates in elastic cache. To update elastic cache you can have a lambda function subscribed to dynamodb change streams.

**Contingencies**

You should have a plan to populate elastic cache in case it goes down and you have to rehydrate the state.

---

**Here are the cons of your options**

**Option A cons:**

1. It will require huge rsu since you will be aggregating results.

**Option B cons:**

1. It will require huge rsu since you will be aggregating results.
2. Directly calling dynamodb from frontend might not be a good idea, considering how you store and retrieve data may evolve over time.
3. See cons of client side rendering.

**Option C cons:**

1. It will require huge rsu since you will be aggregating results.

**Option D cons:**

1. It will require huge rsu since you will be aggregating results.
2. Asynchronous application has their own complexities.

   for example

   if user upvotes and refreshes the page, you may show him that he hasn't casted any vote, since your application is yet to process the sqs event.

   if user first upvotes and then downvotes, your system may store that user has upvoted. Since sqs events are not processed in order.

   Despite the above cons if you still want to take this approach, What you are trying to do here is called Event Sourcing. You should use kafka instead of sqs so that your events are ordered.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, really appreciated.